# SlideToggle Não carrega Maps Corretamente

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

Tenho dois mapas numa página, estou usando slideToggle e slideUp para exibir deixar disponível para visualização apenas um mapa por vez.
mapa_fixo e mapa_movimento são as divs que contem os mapas.

```
#mapa_fixo
{
    display:none;
}

#mapa_movimento
{
    display:none;
}


    function verifica_categoria_carrega_mapa(id)
    {

    var id_categoria = id;


    if(id==1)
    {

        if($("#mapa_fixo").is(":visible") == true)
        {
        }
        else
        {

            $("#mapa_fixo").slideToggle();
            $("#mapa_movimento").slideUp();
            return false;
        }
    }
    else if(id==2)
    {
        if($("#mapa_movimento").is(":visible") == true)
        {
        }
        else
        {

            $("#mapa_fixo").slideUp();
            $("#mapa_movimento").slideToggle();

            gmaps.refresh()

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Tá funcionando, mas, os mapas não estão sendo exibidos corretamente, devido a componentes jquery um dos mapas é carregado num arquivo .js o outro diretamente na página.

Se for carregar os mapas normalmente, sem estar com Display:none, os mapas carregam normalmente.

Mapa Fixo
[image: Mapa Fixo]

Mapa Movimento
[image: Mapa Movimento]

Comment: Você está usando algum plugin externo para fazer isso? O estado inicial do toggle é fechado?

Comment: Para o Toggle não estou usando nenhum plugin, inicialmente setei apenas as divs como display:none, não referenciando o toggle. Se tiver outra forma de fazer isso, mesmo sem usar o toggle, será ótimo.

Comment: Bom, eu tive um problema semelhante, mas no AngularJs (o código era um pouco diferente, não sei dizer como pode se adaptar ao seu modelo). O problema ocorria pois a div do mapa começava como `display:none` também. O que tive que fazer foi aplicar a reinicialização do mapa, que acontece no load do DOM.

Comment: Iniciei usando o `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`, mas, sem sucesso, vi algo relacionado a 
`google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map_rota, 'idle', function()`, mas, não achei metodo para executar, conhece algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.

Iniciei os mapas sem Display:none, e após alguns segundos aplico o Display:none por função.
Os mapas já estão carregados e não ocorre mais o problema

```
window.setTimeout(someFunction, 10000);
function someFunction()
{
    document.getElementById("mapa_fixo").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("mapa_movimento").style.display = "none";
}
```